# C# check if date of upload of the image is newer than some date

Tags: c#, image, file

The user uploads an image which I name as logo.png and I save it in a folder. The user can upload new image anytime he wants. I have 7 files in the same folder.

I get that image via API. At the moment, I download the image every time I run my program. What I need is a flag to know if the user uploaded a new image than the one I already downloaded. If not - don't download the file. if yes - download it. How can I find out if the user uploaded a new file?

I know that I can use a db field for this, but is there a property of the Image class, or the FileSystemInfo class which can tell me this?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a newer image? Creation date? Last modified date?

Comment: @PaulZahra Upload date.

Comment: Do you want to minimize download from your side? Is it critical not to download the same image? If so, you can also store, compute and check some hash of the image file. If user uploaded the same file - you can ignore this.

Comment: @ZuoLi Yes, it's crutial not to download the same image. However, if the user uploads the same image as before, we can download it, it's not a problem

Answer (score 1):

FileSystemInfo has LastWriteTime property which Gets or sets the time when the current file or directory was last written to.

refer this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx